# Can't load ethereum object from metamask-react in TypeScript

Tags: metamask, react, accounts, typescript, npm

I am trying to add this code to handle the change of accounts in `Metamask`...

```
ethereum
  .request({ method: 'eth_accounts' })
  .then(handleAccountsChanged)
  .catch((err: any) => {
    // Some unexpected error.
    // For backwards compatibility reasons, if no accounts are available,
    // eth_accounts will return an empty array.
    console.error(err);
  });

  if (ethereum) {
    // running on client and window + ethereum is avail
    console.log("client")
  } else {
    // you are on the server.
    // OR user does not have a broswer wallet - i.e. metamask
  }
// Note that this event is emitted on page load.
// If the array of accounts is non-empty, you're already
// connected.
ethereum.on('accountsChanged', handleAccountsChanged);
```

...but I am getting the following error in my `TypeScript` project:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'request')
```

`ethereum` has been defined like this, using `metamask-react`:

```
  const { status, connect, account, chainId, ethereum } = useMetaMask();
```

It seems that the object `ethereum` is not being correctly loaded.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although npm page says `ts` support but type for ethereum is `any` in the source code.

```
export declare function useConnectedMetaMask(): {
    account: string;
    chainId: string;
    status: "connected";
} & {
    connect: () => Promise<string[] | null>;
    addChain: (parameters: import("./metamask-context").AddEthereumChainParameter) => Promise<void>;
    switchChain: (chainId: string) => Promise<void>;
    ethereum: any;
};
```

I posted the proper type for Ethereum [in this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961190/property-ethereum-does-not-exist-on-type-window-typeof-globalthis-error/72081301#72081301).

Initially, I had the same error, the request was not sending to pop up the metamask window. It was because I was already connected to the metamask at `localhost:3000` from my other apps. So I manually disconnected and set `useEffect`

```
 const { status, connect, account, chainId, ethereum } = useMetaMask();

useEffect(() => {
    ethereum?.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });

  }, []);
```

when page was loading, I get metamask window pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import { ExternalProvider } from '@ethersproject/providers';

 declare global {
   interface Window {
     ethereum?: ExternalProvider
   }
 }
```

On your `app.tsx` and call ethereum object as `window.ethereum`. The object will be only avaiable if there's any metamask account logged so you need to verify:

```
if(!window.ethereum){
console.log('no ethereum wallet connected')
}
```